# What is the correct term for converting data between client side and server side format?

Tags: javascript, json, terminology

Frequently in web programming in JavaScript, I will take an object of data packaged in a client side format, and convert it to a server side format, or vice versa.

This can mean for example: switching between snake_case and camelCase, replacing nulls with empty strings, perhaps some renaming and restructuring, and adding or ignoring some fields.

What is the correct or best term for such an operation?

I've seen it referred to as serialization, sanitization, or decoration.  I feel like none of these is an exact fit.

Comment: I am not familiar with such a term, but I think your proposed non-exact referrals are indeed not specific to a client->server translation.

Comment: data massaging: converting data to the desired form to be consumed

Comment: There is no "client side" and "server side" formats.

Comment: @amn has a point. Your are translating code/data, it does not seem to matter in this scenario it is from some client's computer to some server.

Comment: @kabanus - you're data processing "pipeline" may have many steps.  I do not know if there is a single work that can encapsulate all of the steps collectively.

Comment: @GlennFerrie Sorry I did not understand that comment.

Comment: Unless "work" is "word"? Which in that case I agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no term for converting data to and from a client-side format to a server-side format, mainly because there doesn't exist such thing as *server-side format* and *client-side format*. Depending on the languages and code conventions used on both sides, data can live in *very* different formats and there is no *server-side format* that encompasses all server-side data formats, likewise for client-side data formats.

Case conversion is just a matter of code conventions in the server and client side. I've never encountered a term that encompasses the concept of case conversion specifically in the case of server-client communication.

So you'll have to invent your own term here. I'd suggest **client-server data mapping**.

Comment: I think this is the answer. The fact Google does not come up quickly on such a buzz word makes it likely that it does not exist, and if it does, it will not be useful for communication.

Comment: There may not be official formats for client and server, but it is often the case that within a company, different teams do the frontend vs backend, so you may have different conventions for their data models.

Comment: Thanks for this response.  A related question would be, what to name the function that does this.  This has me thinking mapDataToClient / mapDataToServer.

Answer (score 1):

I would call what you're doing `mapping`, since you're rearranging your data and renaming variables.

Serialization is the process of converting an object to a string or a "serial" format like binary, but you're doing more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a single term for this. Snake case versus camel case usually involves programming constructs, not data manipulation, and is rarely a server versus client issue.

The only term that comes to mind is "canonicalization", which means converting data into a standard format. This is often done when allowing flexible formats of data coming from the client, but allowing all the modules that process it to be written to expect a more restricted format.

For instance, the back-end code might only understand camel case, but the UI or API allows both snake case and camel case. The main entrypoint would canonicalize everything to camel case.